# QGIS 3.4.10 for Mac users...Digitzing polygons

Tags: qgis, mac, digitizing

I have just installed the LTR version of QGIS (3.4.10) and am having trouble telling QGIS when I have finished a polygon. In fact, I can't.

It used to be in earlier versions that to end a polygon you would type ctrl-click. This is the equivalent to right-click in PCs.

It doesn't work at all in QGIS3.4.10.

Has anybody else encountered the same problem? What is the solution?

[I have tried ctrl-click in other apps such as word, and it functions as it should. I have also completely rebooted the computer but that doesn't help. I am running OS Mojave--10.14.6]

Comment: Does command-click work?

Comment: No, none of the other combinations work either. Option-click; fn-click etc

Comment: I have sort of solved the problem by going into System Preference and then Trackpad and setting the secondary click to "bottom right-hand corner". Ccontrol-click however does not work, even though in other applications( e.g., s\Word, Excel and even on any of the panels in in QGIS) it does

Comment: Seems like it's time to make a bug report: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues. I know in the past the Mac version has been less thoroughly tested than the PC version.